# What is the namespace for CurrencyManager in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the namespace for [CurrencyManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager.aspx) in ASP.NET?

Like in Windows Forms we use System.Windows.Forms namespace for the CurrencyManager class, but for ASP.NET what is the namespace I have to use for the CurrencyManager class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET is a completely different thing than Windows Forms. I suggest you take a look at some tutorials to get familiar with it: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/fundamentals.

Answer (score 3):

I think the first thing you have to realize is the web and a desktop application are completely different animals. There is not really the same sense of databinding on the web as there is for a desktop application because the web is a stateless medium. This means the server sends marked up text to the client or browser upon each request and they are all independant of each other.

So what can you do? You can learn to leverage the ASP.NET AJAX Update panel for your tables. This might be the closest you can get to what you are looking for. Another option is to get pretty intimate with the CSLA or related frameworks, but I think ulitmately you will wind up leveraging AJAX.

The final option is to build your application in Silverlight 2. Since this is essentially a very easy way to build the same interface for the desktop as the web. Of course now you have to learn WPF.

Source:http://forums.asp.net/t/1233986.aspx

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET doesn't have anything similar to `CurrencyManager`: all concepts are different over there.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just use a different namespace, it's a WinForms specific class. You have to find some alternative way of doing what you want.

I'd suggest posting what you'd like to use the class for and then someone might be able to answer with a good alternative.